# Ajax Query not working with range sliders in Laravel

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get value from range slider and update my database using ajax, but it is giving me 404 status error. I am using Laravel.

This is my route:

```
Route::post('developer/work-progress/changeProgess','DeveloperController@changeProgess');
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="form-group row themered">
    <label for="range_02" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label"><b>Back-End</b><span class=" font-13 d-block text-muted clearfix">Set backend progress</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="range_01" name="frontend_percent">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row themered">
    <label for="range_02" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label"><b>Front-End</b>
        <span class=" font-13 d-block text-muted clearfix">Set frontend progress</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="range_02" name="backend_percent">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input class="progressId" type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$order->id}}">
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-info changeProgress">Change</button>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var frontend  = $('#range_01').val();
var backend  = $('#range_02').val();

$('#range_01').change(function () {
    frontend = $(this).val();
});

$('#range_02').change(function () {
    backend = $(this).val(); 
});

$('.changeProgress').click(function () {   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'work-progress/changeProgress',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'frontend_percent' : frontend,
            'backend_percent' : backend,
            'id':   $('.progressId').val()
        },
        headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": token},
        success : function (data) {
            console.log("worked");
        }
     });
});
```

And this is the controller function:

```
public function changeProgess(Request $request) {

    $data = Order::findOrFail($request->id);

    $data->frontend_percent = $request->frontend_percent;
    $data->backend_percent =  $request->backend_percent;

    $data->save();

    return response()->json($data);

}
```

I can see my data in network tab when I inspect as well as the csrf-token.
So I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use a method of the request object, such as "input", like so

```
$request->input('id');
$request->input('frontend_percent');
```

And so forth. You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests
Don't forget to change the version in the url if you are not using 5.6 to reflect your own version.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things that could be causing your issue.

First you need to check if your route is correct.
The easiest way is to put a dd() at the top of your `changeProgess()` function

```
public function changeProgess(Request $request) {
    dd('here');  // test dd
    $data = Order::findOrFail($request->id);
```

If you are getting there then your next step is to find out if the id you are passing exist in your database.

The `findOrFail()` function will return a 404 if you do not have that ID in your database.

The easiest way to do that is to see if you are getting passed that function.

```
public function changeProgess(Request $request) {
    $data = Order::findOrFail($request->id);
    dd($data);  // test dd
```

If you are not getting here then you do not have that `Order` in your database and you will need to check the values you are passing into your form.